# Multiple Regressions on a Single CSV File via sklearn and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have one CSV file called "data.csv". It has five columns T, A, B, C and D

For each tuple of (A,B,C) I have seven data entries in my file corresponding to seven different instances of time T.

I want to perform linear regression on each tuple (A,B,C) over the time series T to predict data D on the next instance of time using the `scikit-learn` library. What is the most efficient way to do select the data and do the regression?

The size of the CSV file is 3.2 GB but I have only 4GB of RAM. I tried to load the complete file at once but my machine is not able to cope up :P

I am using `pandas` to handle the files and `sklearn` for the regression.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regression model, I would suggest SGDRegressor(): http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html
You can load a small portion of the data and train with partial_fit:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
model = SGDRegressor()
model.partial_fit(features, label)
```

For the features it really depends on the problem. You can use the values (A,B,C) at the current time step or all the past values (A,B,C) within a time window of size N. You can also add the predicted values D at the previous time steps as features.

Beside regression, probably you want to take a look at Hidden Markov Model (HMM) or Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) for this type of problem.